# How to update my location when i move and it have to show you are in point 1 radius or not?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

i tried this but its showing my current location first time i get information that i am inside or not . but when i moved outside of radius of point 1 its doesn't showing anything.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    //drawing marker
    LatLng pointOne = new LatLng(23.10,72.50847684);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pointOne).title("Point 1"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)).title("Point 2").snippet("N"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
     //myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    Log.e("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
     LatLng pointTwo = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Show the current location in Google Map
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pointTwo));                  Log.e("location", String.valueOf(pointTwo));

    //drawing overlay circle on marker
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(pointOne)
            .radius(5000)
            .strokeColor(0x40FF0000)
            .fillColor(0x35FF0000));

    //for Checking marker is inside or not
    float[] distance = new float[2];

    Location.distanceBetween( pointTwo.latitude, pointTwo.longitude,
            circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

    if( distance[0] > circle.getRadius()  ){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    pointToPosition(pointOne);
}
```

Thanks for Help In advance

Comment: Try GeoFencing aPI --> suits your need to make a virtual fence where if someone exits, an event gets triggered

Comment: i appreciate that but i am little confuse that how to do that?

Comment: And one new problem Sometime its works and Sometime it get nullpointer excetion

Comment: Location Manager gives locations via a Call back in onLocationChanged(). This is asynchronous and it will not return a results until the GPS/NETWORK fix is achieved. Thus it can throw a Null pointer if accessed before the fix is achieved....

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Google GeoFencing API to draw a virtual circle of some radius around the location.On user's entry/exit an event will be triggered which will help your cause.

Now `getLastKnownLocation()` which you are using May or May Not provide a location value. LocationManager maintains GPS location data until that data becomes outdate in like 8mins odd. After this, there will again be a cold startup and the GPS in your phone will try to get a fix and return results.

In case this is a cold startup, you can also get a `NullPointerException` because of the fact that the your last know location is outdated.

You can try a `requestLocationUpdates()` .... if lastKnownLocation returns a Null result...

This will cause the LocationManager to explicitly call the GPS in your phone to search for the current location... this will provide results in a callback function `onLocationChanged`... here you can get the current location....

Comment: thanks For Answer but It Working Correctly below Api Level 23 on Api level 23 its not working

Comment: :) np mate... as long as it works for you it's great.

Comment: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled showing on API 23